# IE 8 fireEvent Unspecified error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, onclick

I get through ajax call some text file and I need to save it on client side, I found a code that helped me with this (it's working in Opera, Chrome, FireFox), but in IE 8 it doesn't want to working, I'm getting "Unspecified error" in fireEvent line. Could you help me to understand, what is wrong?

```
var url = 'data:application/octet-stream,' + responseData;
                var anchor = document.createElement('a');
                anchor.setAttribute('href', url);
                anchor.setAttribute('download', fileName);

                var e;
                if (document.createEvent) {
                    var e = window.document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                    e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                    anchor.dispatchEvent(e);
                } else if (window.document.createEventObject) {
                    try {
                        var clickEvent = document.createEventObject();
                        clickEvent.button = 1;
                        anchor.fireEvent('onclick', clickEvent); // <-- there is error "Unspecified error"

                    } catch (ex) {
                        alert(ex);
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be because the target element is not in the document.